# How does the framework know which api is been called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gateway

How does the framework know which api is been called?

```
app.get('/user/:userId/name/export', function (req, res) {
   var userId = req.params.userId;
}

app.get('/user/:userId/name/:name', function (req, res) {
   var userId = req.params.userId;
   var name = req.params.name
}
```

I'm working on an api gateway, need some customization of access control. It need to block the api call and check the roles of user through the params in path, like userId and name in db. If matched the config in file, will pass the acl and call the api, otherwise, will return 401. So if the url pattern is similar, I found it's hard to distinguish two api which is exactly been call. Any suggestions? Really appreciate for you help!

Comment: You can use Express Middleware concept, It will call before api check 3 links: [Writing Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html),   [Using Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html),  [Example](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/13/build-and-understand-express-middleware-through-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Express router](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) calls each callback, which match the URL path.
Route `/user/123/name/admin` matches only the second path, but route `/user/123/name/export` matches both of them.
If you end the request on the first callback, then the second will never be called:

```js
app.get('/user/:userId/name/export', function (req, res) {
   var userId = req.params.userId;
   res.end();
}

app.get('/user/:userId/name/:name', function (req, res) {
   var userId = req.params.userId;
   var name = req.params.name
}
```

Callbacks will be called according to adding sequence. So the global paths, like `app.get('*', ...)` must be added at the very end.